# Generalizing Radix Sort uint64_t code from 32 MSB and 48 MSB to 40 MSB sort bits

Tags: c, performance, sorting, radix

Is it possible to generalize this Radix Sort code to look at only the 40 most significant bits of uint64_t data?

Generalizing the 32 sort bit code from user RGCLGR to 48 and 64 bits and comparing sorting a uint64_t[36M] on 64, 48 and 32 bits:

```
Time=  3.130 sec = 20.342%, RADIX_SORT_UINT64_REG, hits=4, 0.782 sec each
Time=  2.336 sec = 15.180%, RADIX_SORT_UINT64_48R, hits=4, 0.584 sec each
Time=  1.540 sec = 10.007%, RADIX_SORT_UINT64_32R, hits=4, 0.385 sec each
```

This confirms the expected linearity between bits sorted and time to sort.

I have a need to sort hundreds of uint64_t[]s on only the 34 Most Significant Bits. The 48 MSB sort works, but sorting on only 40 bits should take ~5/6 as long. This could reduce a 58 second travail to a mere 48 second ordeal for the user.

The difference between the 32 MSB code and the 48 MSB code is mostly slight variations except for one code segment:

32 bit code segment radix sorting mIndex [0, 1, 2, 3]:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {       /* radix sort */
    u = pData[i];
    pTemp[mIndex[3][(u >> 32) & 0xff]++] = u;
}
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    u = pTemp[i];
    pData[mIndex[2][(u >> 40) & 0xff]++] = u;
}
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    u = pData[i];
    pTemp[mIndex[1][(u >> 48) & 0xff]++] = u;
}
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    u = pTemp[i];
    pData[mIndex[0][(u >> 56) & 0xff]++] = u;
}
```

The 48 bit segment prepends this code to handle mIndex [4, 5]:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {       /* radix sort */
    u = pData[i];
    pTemp[mIndex[5][(u >> 16) & 0xff]++] = u;
}
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {       
    u = pTemp[i];
    pData[mIndex[4][(u >> 24) & 0xff]++] = u;
}
```

Converting to full 64 bit sorting adds similar code to operate on matrix indexes [6, 7]

Is it even possible to add mIndex[4] to create a 40 MSB sort?
The pData array is used with even mIndex indexes.
The pTemp array is used with odd  mIndex indexes.

Is this method limited to being generalized only for even byte counts?

## ===================================

Full code for sorting a uint64[] on the 32 most significant bits:

```
// From code submitted by on stackoverflow.com rcgldr, Nov 3 2017
void radix_sort_r64_32(uint64_t *pData, uint64_t *pTemp, size_t count,    
EV_TIME_STR *tsa)
{
    size_t mIndex[4][256] = { 0 };      /* index matrix */
size_t * pmIndex;                   /* ptr to row of matrix */
size_t i, j, m, n;
uint64_t u;
if(tsa)  time_event(E_RADIX_SORT_UINT64_32R, tsa, E_TIME_EVENT, 1, 0);  

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {       /* generate histograms */
    u = pData[i];
    mIndex[3][(u >> 32) & 0xff]++;
    mIndex[2][(u >> 40) & 0xff]++;
    mIndex[1][(u >> 48) & 0xff]++;
    mIndex[0][(u >> 56) & 0xff]++;
}

for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {           /* convert to indices */
    pmIndex = mIndex[j];
    n = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        m = pmIndex[i];
        pmIndex[i] = n;
        n += m;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {       /* radix sort */
    u = pData[i];
    pTemp[mIndex[3][(u >> 32) & 0xff]++] = u;
}
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    u = pTemp[i];
    pData[mIndex[2][(u >> 40) & 0xff]++] = u;
}
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    u = pData[i];
    pTemp[mIndex[1][(u >> 48) & 0xff]++] = u;
}
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    u = pTemp[i];
    pData[mIndex[0][(u >> 56) & 0xff]++] = u;
}
}  // End Radix_Sort_R64_32().
```

======================

And the diff between the 32 bit and the 48 bit sort versions:

```
diff ~/tmp/radix.sort.32.c    ~/tmp/radix.sort.48.c
< < void radix_sort_r64_32(uint64_t *pData, uint64_t *pTemp, size_t count,
< ---
< > void radix_sort_r64_48(uint64_t *pData, uint64_t *pTemp, size_t count,
< 
< <     size_t mIndex[4][256] = { 0 };      /* index matrix */
< ---
< >     size_t mIndex[6][256] = { 0 };      /* index matrix */
< 
< <       if(tsa)  time_event(E_RADIX_SORT_UINT64_32R, tsa, E_TIME_EVENT, 1, 0);  
< ---
< >       if(tsa)  time_event(E_RADIX_SORT_UINT64_48R, tsa, E_TIME_EVENT, 1, 0);  
< 
< ---
< >         mIndex[5][(u >> 16) & 0xff]++;  // B2
< >         mIndex[4][(u >> 24) & 0xff]++;  // B3
< 
< <     for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {           /* convert to indices */
< ---
< >     for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {           /* convert to indices */
< 
< >         pTemp[mIndex[5][(u >> 16) & 0xff]++] = u;
< >     }
< >     for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {       /* radix sort */
< >         u = pTemp[i];
< >         pData[mIndex[4][(u >> 24) & 0xff]++] = u;
< >     }
< >     for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {       /* radix sort */
< >         u = pData[i];
< 44c56
< < }  // End Radix_Sort_R64_32().
< ---
< > }  // End Radix_Sort_R64_48().
```

Executive summary of unique differences:

```
Unique lines from "~/tmp/radix.sort.32.c":
  02) void radix_sort_r64_32(uint64_t *pData, uint64_t *pTemp, size_t count,
  05) size_t mIndex[4][256] = { 0 };      /* index matrix */
  19) for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {           /* convert to indices */

Unique lines from "~/tmp/radix.sort.48.c":
  01) void radix_sort_r64_48(uint64_t *pData, uint64_t *pTemp, size_t count,
  04) size_t mIndex[6][256] = { 0 };      /* index matrix */
  14) mIndex[5][(u >> 16) & 0xff]++;  // B2
  15) mIndex[4][(u >> 24) & 0xff]++;  // B3
  22) for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {           /* convert to indices */
  34) pTemp[mIndex[5][(u >> 16) & 0xff]++] = u;
  38) pData[mIndex[4][(u >> 24) & 0xff]++] = u;
```

Comment: `diff -u` output is generally a lot easier to read.